# Every page into cookies to faster "go back" process

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, back

Is it possible to use cookies, to let users browse faster in a site with a lot of jquery modules? I mean, that every time when someone clicks browsers back button, he goes back to the page which was in it memory (every page module would be in exactly that position in which it was when user got out from that page).

Comment: It's possible, but you don't need cookies in this case.

Comment: Hmm.. I would be realy graetful if you would lead me to the source where I could learn to do such a things. :) Searching for it for entire two days, and can't understand how to do it corectly, it starts to drive me crazy.

Comment: Have you determined why this process is slow?

Comment: Process is slow because of animation of jquery modules. The animation of opening vertical accordion (which I want only for firs time) slows down user browsing. So I want browser to remember where everything was when user clicked link, and then he comes back, everything would be in their possition when he left.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might find pushState and history useful for this: [Manipulating the Browser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Using these techniques, you can change what information is requested when the browser's back button is used.